# Add decimal point for my Calculator

Tags: ios, xcode, decimal, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator. Everything works fine, but now I want to add a decimal point and I do not know how. Can you please help? Thank you.

I tried this

```
- (IBAction) buttondecimal {
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + @".";
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%0.f", SelectNumber]; }
```

, but I get an error: Invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'NSString *')

**Here is my code:**

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int Method;
double SelectNumber;
double RunningTotal;

@interface KalkulackaViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UILabel *deglabel;
IBOutlet UIButton *degbutton;
IBOutlet UITextField *Screen;
}

-(IBAction)Number1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Nasobeni:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Deleni:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Minus:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Plus:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Rovnase:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)AllClear:(id)sender;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "KalkulackaViewController.h"

@interface KalkulackaViewController ()

@end

@implementation KalkulackaViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10,10)];
    Screen.rightView = paddingView;
    Screen.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    Screen.leftView = paddingView;
    Screen.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
}
-(IBAction)Number1:(id)sender
{
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 1;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.f", SelectNumber];
}
- (IBAction) buttondecimal
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectNumber` is a `double`, you can't add a string to it like you were doing with `@"."`.

What you're most likely going to have to do is just store the values in the string (instead of in `SelectNumber`). So for example, if you're adding the number "1" in the calculator:

```
Screen.text = [Screen.text stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
```

The same goes for the decimal point (although you should check to see if it contains a decimal already):

```
if ([screen.text rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound) {
    screen.text = [screen.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
}
```

Then, to get the value out of the string for actual calculations, you can just use `doubleValue`:

```
double value = [screen.text doubleValue];
```

Doing it like this also gives you the ability to add a backspace key if you wanted to:

```
if (screen.text.length > 0) {
    screen.text = [screen.text substringToIndex:screen.text.length - 1];
}
```

Also, sidenote: You shouldn't be naming your variables starting with capital letters. Camelcase is the standard for Objective-C (and is accepted in general). Example: `runningTotal`, `selectNumber`. The same goes for function names, etc. The main reason is that things starting with capital letters are generally class names, so this improves readability and reduces confusion.

Comment: Thx for your help, but if I use for add numbers your code (for example Screen.text = [Screen.text stringByAppendingString:@"1"];), a calculator stops working, because it works with SelectNumber :/

Comment: Well the point was that you need to change the way you're creating your calculator and NOT make it use `SelectNumber`. All 3 answers say that.

Comment: Well, I will follow your advice ;-)

Comment: I have one more question. I made button +/- code: if(![Screen.text  isEqual: @"0"] && [Screen.text rangeOfString:@"-"].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@", Screen.text];
    }, adding minus works great, but I do not know how to remove minus if I click again on the button.

Comment: You may not want to actually add the minus sign to the string. But if you'd like to remove it, you can use the backspace example I posted in my answer if it's the last character, or you can use the `replaceOccurancesOfString:withString:` method of `NSString`.

Comment: Thank a lot. Method replaceOccurancesOfString:withString: works great!

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, you cannot add a string (`@"."`) to a variable that is a `double` type. You need to store your `SelectNumber` as an NSString and append characters to it as the user presses buttons, and then convert it to a double when using it to calculate the answer.

You can convert it back to a double using:

```
[SelectNumber doubleValue];
```

If you do not store it as a string, you would have to do complicated procedures to determine that the next number pressed should be after a decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a double to string. Two different data types, so it is not allowed.

You can do something like this:

```
-(IBAction)decimalPressed:(id)sender {
    calcScreen.text = [calcScreen.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
}

-(IBAction)numberPressed:(id)sender {
    calcScreen.text = [calcScreen.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[sender tag]]];
}

-(IBAction)operationPressed:(id)sender {
    selectedNumber = [calcScreen.text floatValue];
    ...
}
```

Comment: `[sender tag]` is not a string.